# How to validate Types before calling setValueForKey

Tags: swift

I want to use setValueForKey to set object properties from a dictionary. If the dictionary has the wrong data in it (eg: data is `String` but property is `Double`) the setValueForKey function crashes.

To stop this crash I added a type comparison like so:

```
if type(of: propertyValue) == type(of: dataValue) {
    // Data is the correct type
    setValue(dataValue, forKey: property)
}
```

The problem here is that if the data has `1` the type is `Int` and this will not be written to a `Double` type property even though the setValueForKey would work fine here.

How do I check if the data type can be casted to the property type without crashing on setValueForKey?

**Edit**

The crash I had was the other way around. When tried to call setValueForKey with a `Double` while the property is `String` I get this crash:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I should have specified this in the original post but this is the plan.

I'm making a super class that I can initialise with a dictionary. The init method should be in the super class and should set all the subclass properties.

```
class DictionaryClass: NSObject {
    init?(_ data: [String: Any]) {
        super.init()

        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        // Loop over properties
        for arg in mirror.children {
            // If data has no value for property return nil
            // If data has wrong type of value for property return nil
            // Else do setValueForKey
        }
    }
}
```

The goal:

```
class Example: DictionaryClass {
    var someNumber: Double = 0
    var coolString: String = ""
}

let data: [String: Any] = ["someNumber": 2, "coolString": "Example"]
let example = Example(data) 

print(example.coolString) // "Example"

let data2: [String: Any] = ["someNumber": 2, "coolString": 4]
let example2 = Example(data2) // nil

let data3: [String: Any] = ["someNumber": 2]
let example3 = Example(data3) // nil
```

There is a bit more to it but this is the basic idea, if there is a more Swifty way of doing this I am all ears.

Comment: And if you are doing the type comparison and then trying to set a value of type `Int` to a key of type `Double` it isn't practically right, is it? Why will you set an `Int` to a `Double` type then?

Comment: @nayem I didn't specify in the post but the data that comes in is from JSON so comes in as `[String: Any]` but when the `Any` is `1` type(of:) returns `Int`

Comment: "if there is a more Swifty way of doing this I am all ears" Swift really is not set up for this kind of thing at all. As you've already discovered, Mirror takes you only so far; introspection is limited, and types (as I said in my answer) are static. If you need something that flexible, why not just use a dictionary? (Or wrap a dictionary.) Basically you are trying to turn Swift into a completely different _language_. Maybe you should write this class in Objective-C!

Comment: @matt Alright thank you for your help, I don't think I am skilled enough in Objective-C to create this so I will let the project rest for a while. I don't really understand why setValueForKey is available in Swift if I can't check if it will crash or not.

Comment: It’s not part of Swift. It’s an Objective-C Cocoa Foundation feature.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Swift's typing is static, not dynamic. You cannot cast to `type(of: dataValue)`; you have to say the name of the type *explicitly* in order to cast it. Thus you have to know *at compile time* what the type will be. If you know that, then you can test safely with `as?`.

Also, as you rightly point out, there is no need for any explicit cast. That's because `setValue:forKey:` and KVC are Objective-C, so all of this is passing through Objective-C and NSNumber.

On the other hand, I can't reproduce the reported crash. In my testing, passing a String through `setValue:forKey:` where a Double is expected does not crash; it just gives zero:

```
class C2 : NSObject {
    @objc var dataValue : Double = 2
    func test() {
        self.setValue("howdy", forKey: "dataValue")
    }
}
let c2 = C2()
c2.test()
print(c2.dataValue) // 0.0
```

Even more broadly, I'd question why you're using KVC at all. You have not shown any context whatever, but I'm betting there's a better, Swiftier way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you are correct on the crash not working, I described it the wrong way around. I edited my question to have a bit more context. If you could look at it I would really appreciate it!